# MySQL performance between multi join queries vs. using function

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I have a table which is named: `candidate_info` has three columns are `id_user`, `id_type` and `value`:

- id_type = 1 => Fullname
- id_type = 2 => Email
- id_type = 3 => Mailing Address
- id_type = 4 => Phone number

to store user information:

I consider two queries as below, it will combine from rows to columns:

Form Original:

```
Id User | Id Type | Value
1       | 1       | John
1       | 2       | john@g.com
1       | 3       | Ho Chi Minh
1       | 4       | 123
2       | 1       | Ana
2       | 2       | ana@g.com
2       | 3       | New York
2       | 4       | 456
```

To New:

```
Id User | Fullname | Email        | Mailing_Address | Phone Number
1       | John     | john@g.com   | Ho Chi Minh     | 123
2       | Ana      | ana@g.com    | New York        | 456
```

**1. First query:**

```
select
    c1.id_user,
    c1.value as fullname,
    c2.value as email,
    c3.value as mailing_address,
    c4.value as phone_number
from
    candidate_info c1
        left join
    candidate_info c2 ON c1.id_user = c2.id_user
        left join
    candidate_info c3 ON c1.id_user = c3.id_user
        left join
    candidate_info c4 ON c1.id_user = c4.id_user
where
    c1.id_type = 1
    and c2.id_type = 2
    and c3.id_type = 3
    and c4.id_type = 4;
```

**2. Second query**

```
select 
    c.id_user,
    MAX(IF(c.id_type = 1, c.value, NULL)) as fullname,
    MAX(IF(c.id_type = 2, c.value, NULL)) as email,
    MAX(IF(c.id_type = 3, c.value, NULL)) as mailing_address,
    MAX(IF(c.id_type = 4, c.value, NULL)) as phone_number
from
    candidate_info c
where
    c.id_type in (1, 2, 3, 4)
group by c.id_user
```

Which is better?

Edit: Change `id_entry_field` to `id_type`, `join` to `left join` to make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second query is better because it doesn't create a large cartesian product as the first query does. Instead, it iterates over the table's records only once, emitting a row containing aggregate data for each group.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot compare queries that return different results. The first version will filter out users who don't have 4 records ; the second one - won't.

If you used `LEFT JOIN` in the first one, the comparison would make sense. In that case I'd bet on the second one; one day I compared performance (not on mysql though) of two approaches, Oracle showed 1st version better with number of joins up to 2; with greater number the second approach outperformed...

Comment: Adding a "having count(1) = 4" to the second query is a step toward similar results, but then assumes that there is a unique index over id_user and id_entry_field.

Comment: @Fls'Zen: using `having` gives similar results, but won't give the same execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

The other comments are right about the queries yielding different results.  Assuming that each row does have all the entires (1,2,3,4), I'd say run a test app to benchmark them.  e.g. Time running the query a few thousand times and see which one is faster on average.